# How can I show users Google analytics data, on my website?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have a SEO website, and want to show   google analytics  data of users.

I can  retrieve my own website google analytics data   via google Reporting API version 4 php client , but how can I retrieve others Google analytics data ? Users after registration  gives  only  theirs email and tracked website url, what  else I need to make php client request  ?

How can I do it ?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To show the Google analytical data. You have to add the website url into your Google analytical account.

You must be the owner of your account. Add as many websites as you wanted
to add the website of users.

You have to follow the steps as you added your website.
That means user has to add the code into their website which will be provided when we add a new website in Analytical account.

Once added the data will be shown to the main account holder.
then you have to provide the access to the User whom you want to show.

Comment: How  programmatically   add permissions  and  grants   ?